# KDE Plasma icons showing in UBUNTU DESKTOP

Tags: 20.04, desktop-environments, plasma

I downloaded KDE PLASMA DESKTOP in my Ubuntu 20.04.3 computer and i used it to review. I didnt like it so i switched back to UBUNTU in log in screen but the icons, cursor and Window layout is still KDE PLASMA. I panicked an uninstalled KDE PLASMA using the command

```
sudo apt-get remove plasma-desktop kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

But still no change. I will link a SREENSHOT here.[image]

Someone please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you installed KDE plasma, it also installed the KDE icon theme (`breeze`). You need to use GNOME Tweaks and set your Icons again to the default Ubuntu Icon theme (`Yaru`).

1. Install GNOME Tweaks to configure your icon theme:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks
   ```
2. Open GNOME Tweaks:

   ```
   sudo gnome-tweaks
   ```
3. Navigate to *Appearance → Icon → Yaru*
4. Save the changes and quit GNOME tweaks.
5. Log out and Log in again to prevent lags.

Comment: This method worked fine for me. I installed gnome tweaks and changed the icons and applications to yaru and yaru dark respectively. The icons on the desktop remained as breeze icons til a restart.

Comment: Can You just say one more thing, How can i remove all the apps(klipper, konquerer, kwallet etc.) downloaded with PLASMA DESKTOP?

ThankYou

Answer (score 1):

A better solution, which will allow you the choice of whether you wish to keep your KDE Plasma Desktop or not. Also it should not mess with your KDE Plasma Desktop icons

From the Ubuntu desktop

Open **Terminal** and enter the following commands

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme

gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme
```

One should then see your icons change back to Ubuntu's default

The Desktop icons may not change immediately, if so
simply log out and log back in